# Obtaining attribute values from emulator Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am working on a mobile automation project and I am having issues obtaining an attribute value(Example a radio button if it is checked or a checked box that is not checked). I am using By `org.openqa.selenium.By` class but I see this class doesn't count with methods like `isEnabled()`, is Checked(), `getText()` like `Webdriver` does, And I am getting an error casting it to SearchContext class to be able to obtain the attribute value.

```
ExamplePage.locationSharingSwitch.findElement((SearchContext);
ExamplePage.locationSharingSwitch).isEnabled();
```

Getting this error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be
> cast to org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to get attribute is

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("someId");
String isEnabled = element.getAttribute("enabled");
```

From my experience, element can be disabled and still "enabled" value is "true". it really depends on component implementation, so I would not rely on it in 100% cases.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I was trying that approach but since we don't use driver to find elements it became difficult to me to get an elements attribute's value, but let me check if this works. Thanks